# How to run scheduled tasks in Orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, timer, orchardcms

I have to run a automated job every 5 hours.

I found this post on how to create scheduled tasks, using IScheduledTaskHandler and IScheduledTaskManager. 
[Scheduled tasks using Orchard CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916146/scheduled-tasks-using-orchard-cms)

I copied the same code, I added my service call inside the Process function. It compiles fine. But I am not sure if I have to 'start' this scheduled task, like a windows service start. Does it get picked up automatically after I build the solution? When does the clock starts ticking if I want to run this job in 5 hours? And if I want to stop/pause, how can I do that?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I am getting an exception if I try to enable the custom module with task handler.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

```
Line 241: var shellContext = _shellContexts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Settings.Name == settings.Name);
```

Source File: \orchard-1.4\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.cs    Line: 241

The _shellContexts is coming up as null. If I remove the task handler class from the project/module, everything works fine.

Here is the task handler code.

```
public class ScheduledTaskHandler : IScheduledTaskHandler
{
    private const string TaskType = "MyTaskUniqueID";
    private readonly IScheduledTaskManager _taskManager;
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public ScheduledTaskHandler(IScheduledTaskManager taskManager, IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _taskManager = taskManager;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
        try
        {
            DateTime firstDate = new DateTime().AddMinutes(5);
            ScheduleNextTask(firstDate);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.Logger.Error(e, e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Process(ScheduledTaskContext context)
    {
        if (context.Task.TaskType == TaskType)
        {
            try
            {
                _myService.RunJob();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.Logger.Error(e, e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                DateTime nextTaskDate = new DateTime().AddHours(5);
                ScheduleNextTask(nextTaskDate);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ScheduleNextTask(DateTime date)
    {
        if (date > DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            var tasks = this._taskManager.GetTasks(TaskType);
            if (tasks == null || tasks.Count() == 0)
                this._taskManager.CreateTask(TaskType, date, null);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This is a generic exception thrown by FirstOrDefault() - `_shellContexts` is null for some reason. Could you show your task handler code? Btw - check how the task handlers should be written eg. in Orchard.PublishLater module. Maybe you did something wrong. But cannot say anything until I could see the whole picture.

Comment: The code is almost same as what was in the other example. I have pasted it above.

Comment: Looking at the error log, I see this exception...............................
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Orchard.IOrchardServices, Orchard.Data.ISessionFactoryHolder, Orchard.Data.ISessionLocator, IMyQuery)' on type 'MyServices'. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at MyServices..ctor(IOrchardServices orchardServices, ISessionFactoryHolder sessionFactoryHolder, ISessionLocator sessionLocator, IMyQuery myQuery)

Comment: Are you trying to do something inside `MyServices` ctor, that could possibly throw null reference exception? Don't put any complex logic in there, or make sure you do necessary checks.

Comment: This is the line that's failing.............................................................................................................. contentrepo = _orchardServices.WorkContext.Resolve<IRepository<SomeRecord>>();

Comment: If I comment out the above line, I don't get any exception. Is WorkContext not available when using scheduled task?

Comment: It's not available in ctor. Do not do anything besides simple assignments in ctor, ever. Autofac needs to construct the whole dependency tree first. If you need to call `Resolve()` directly - do that when you actually need it. Second thing - if you need to access a repository simply inject it in ctor, as you did with other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clock starts ticking automatically when you start the app - you cannot stop/pause it.

Scheduler runs in 1 minute intervals - it checks if there are tasks that should be ran now and runs them. Tasks are being stored in database - corresponding record is always deleted just before task execution is about to start (to ensure that a given task will run only once).

If you need a recurrent job to be ran, you need to create a new task just after the previous one has finished (like in the example you linked to).

Comment: What do you mean by 'when you start the app'? This task handler is in one my custom modules. I am guessing the clock starts when this module is enabled from the admin dashboard?

Comment: Exactly that - when application starts. Task scheduler is one of the default components in Orchard - it's always running in background. Task handler, which you are talking about, is a class called by the scheduler every minute. There can be (and in fact are) lots of task handlers (from other modules) - scheduler grabs them all and calls each one once per minute.

Answer (score 1):

if somebody is interested I've simply removed the starter code from ScheduledTaskHandler. 
The following I put on some controller constructor

```
private void ScheduleStartTask() {
    var tasks = _scheduledTaskManager.GetTasks(TaskType);
    if (tasks == null || tasks.Count() == 0) {

        var date = _clock.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5);

        _scheduledTaskManager.CreateTask(TaskType, date, null);
    }
}
```

and on the handler

```
public void Process(ScheduledTaskContext context) {
        if (context.Task.TaskType == TaskType) {
            try {

                var x = "kuku";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.Logger.Error(e, e.Message);
            } finally {

                this.ScheduleNextTask();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ScheduleNextTask() {
        var date = _clock.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5);
        _taskManager.DeleteTasks(null, a => a.TaskType == TaskType);
        _taskManager.CreateTask(TaskType, date, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ILoggerFactory Instead of ILogger and then Get Logger Instance from it.

```
public ScheduledTaskHandler(IScheduledTaskManager taskManager,ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory, IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _taskManager = taskManager;
        Logger = NLoggerFactory.CreateLogger(typeof(ScheduledTaskHandler));;
        try
        {
            DateTime firstDate = new DateTime().AddMinutes(5);
            ScheduleNextTask(firstDate);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.Logger.Error(e, e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry did not read carefully and thought it was logger issue. One question, Did your service interface(IMyService) implements IDependency ?

Comment: Yes, it does implement IDependency.