# A background running feature in Orchard

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, orchardcms

So what I'm trying to do is an Orchard Feature that **if enabled**, runs a separate thread (**service**) that queries **IRepository<>** of some **PartRecord**.

#### About Starting the service:

I tried starting the service on **IFeatureEventHandler.Enabled()**, but this gets **executed only on enabling the feature**, not when Orchard is started.

So i looked in the Orchard framework for anything that i can use and i found **IOrchardShellEvents.Activated()**.

So I basicly did this:

```
 public class MyService : IOrchardShellEvents {

    ...More stuff...

    public void Activated() {
        running = true;
        //Run DoWork() in separate thread
    }

    public void Terminating() {
        running = false;
    }
     
    private void DoWork(){
        //do service work while running = true
    }

}
```

This happened to work, but I'm not sure if this is the common practice for starting a custom defined thread when Orchard starts. So **please correct me** if it's not done like this..

#### About Repository querying problem:

The repository gets injected and at first it queries the table just fine. After a while tho, it throws an exception saying that: ***"Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported."***.

It seems extremely bizzare, that a query that get executed a couple of times crashes after a while;
Here's the code for the shows how i use the repository:

```
 public MyService(ServiceManager manager, IRepository<SomePartRecord> repo) {
        this.manager = manager;
        //The manager of the service uses the repository to get a single column(ExpectaId, not a PK) out of each row
        manager.LoadIds = () =>
              repo.Table.ToList().Select(record => record.ExpectaId);
    }
```

**Note:** The Func<> manager.LoadIds is called once per 10 seconds

**Note:** I'm using MySql Server 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the answer to any question beginning with "how do I spin a separate thread in order to..." is "don't". Seriously. See for example http://ayende.com/blog/158945/thou-shall-not-do-threading-unless-you-know-what-you-are-doing

Fortunately, Orchard provides a way to run tasks in the background without having to spin your own threads: [How to run scheduled tasks in Orchard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475187/how-to-run-scheduled-tasks-in-orchard)

Comment: Ah, yes, this is way more elegant. Thanks!