# Cannot access a disposed object exception when using IScheduledTaskManager in Orchard CMS

Tags: task, orchardcms

I have followed this post to build a scheduled task at the end of each month

[Scheduled tasks using Orchard CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916146/scheduled-tasks-using-orchard-cms)

```
private void ScheduleNextTask(DateTime date)
    {
        if (date > DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            var tasks = _taskManager.GetTasks(TaskType);
            if (tasks == null || tasks.Count() == 0)
                _taskManager.CreateTask(TaskType, date, null);
        }
    }
```

This works fine in orchard 1.4, but when I upgraded to 1.5.1, It thorws an error everytime I enable/disable module, change themes, or edit source code while debugging. This is the error

```
Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'TransactionScope'
```

If I comment all the lines access to _taskManager in method ScheduleNextTask, no more error. I don't know why but I need the task running, so anyone can give me an advice?