# How to make sure a scheduled task runs only once Orchard CMS

Tags: scheduled-tasks, orchardcms

I need to create a one-off scheduled task in Orchard CMS, which is kicked off when a custom content type is published.

I have a scheduledTask handler:

```
public class MyCustomTaskHandler : IScheduledTaskHandler
{
    private const string TaskType = "MyCustomTask";
    private readonly IMyCustomService _customService;
    private readonly IScheduledTaskManager _taskManager;

    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public MyCustomTaskHandler(IMyCustomService customService, IScheduledTaskManager taskManager)
    {
        _customService = customService;
        _taskManager = taskManager;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;

    }

    public void Process(ScheduledTaskContext context)
    {
        if (context.Task.TaskType == TaskType)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.Information("Proceesing scheduled task of content item #{0}", context.Task.ContentItem.Id);

                _customService.Execute(context.Task.ContentItem);
                _taskManager.DeleteTasks(null, a => a.TaskType == TaskType);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.Logger.Error(e, e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

And after my content item is published I use this code to create the scheduled task.

```
_contentManager.Publish(item);

//set off background task
_scheduledTaskManager.CreateTask("MyCustomTask", DateTime.UtcNow, item);
```

However it runs twice each time *and* it continues to run (twice) every minute. I only want it to run once and then delete. What am I missing? Is ScheduledTaskHandler the wrong interface to implement?

Note - I've already read through [How to run scheduled tasks in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475187/how-to-run-scheduled-tasks-in-orchard) and [Scheduled Tasks using Orchard CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916146/scheduled-tasks-using-orchard-cms) but neither seem to contain the answer / have the problem I'm getting

UPDATE: I've also been looking into IBackgroundTask rather than IScheduledTask(Handler) but I can't tell how to "fire" the event rather than it just running continually in the background, so I'm back to not knowing how to run a one off / singular task.

(I'm going to look into setting a flag on the content type to say it's ready to be packaged, and then setting the flag to "off" once it's fired to try and make sure it only runs once - but this feels like a super-bodge-job to me :/

Comment: You do not need to use the TaskManager to delete the Task, after it is triggered it is automatically removed. Apart from that the code should work.

Comment: It's not being deleted (whether I use the _taskManager or not), the code is firing twice every (approx) minute (as explained above). I have no idea why as I assumed it would only run once like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I don't think a scheduled task is what you need. If I understand you correctly, you just want to run a task when a content type is published. So what I think would be the correct way to achieve this would to hook into the OnPublished event in a ContentHandler. This is triggered when a part is published.

Here is a bit of pseudo-esque code I wrote in notepad...

```
namespace MyModule
{
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public class MyPartHandler : ContentHandler
    {
        private readonly ICustomService customService;

        public MyPartHandler(IRepository<MyPartRecord> repository, ICustomService customService)
        {
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
            this.customService = customService;

            OnPublished<MyPart>((context, part) => {
                if(part.ContentItem.ContentType != "MyContentType")
                    return;

                customService.Exeggcute(part);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess so... but I really want this to run as some kind of task rather than something that would hold up what the front end user is doing. If the routine takes a long time to run, and is in the OnPublished event, wouldn't it hold up the page refresh for the user?

Comment: I don't really know others thoughts on this but it seems to me that creating content is kinda thread specific and creating other threads to handle tasks for the original thread may get messy.

Comment: Perhaps it might help if I explain the use case - Once a content type is published, I need to set up a job that will go to a particular directory, zip up the contents (might be *very* large and therefore take a little while to run). I have no problems with the code itself, and there's no need for the zip to be immediately available. However it's not acceptable if the user clicks "publish" and then the page hangs. This is why I felt some kind of background task is better, but I do see what you're saying about hooking into events, I just still feel that that's not the right way to go

Comment: Okay, I sorta see where you are coming from. I have never actually used the background task stuff but if I were you I would probably schedule the event where you do your zipping for maybe a minute after publishing and execute it then. An example of something like this can probably be found in the Orchard.PublishLater module. That is where I would begin :) sorry I cant be more help

Comment: Hello, did you solve this ? I have the same problem! Thanks !